# Spring Integration XML to Java HowTo - Multiple @ServiceActivator from same class with different parameters

Tags: spring-integration

While translating Spring Batch and Spring Integration from xml to Java I've seen a class used for multiple @ServiceActivator with different inputChannel and folders after files been. Looks like this:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class ServiceActivatorClass implements InitializingBean {
    private Job job;
    private String doneFolder;
    private String errorFolder;
    private Database database;


public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    Assert.notNull(job, "A Job must be provided");
    Assert.notNull(doneFolder, "done folder must be provided");
    Assert.notNull(errorFolder, "error folder must be provided");
    Assert.notNull(database, "error database must be provided");
}

@ServiceActivator
public JobLaunchRequest adapt(File file) throws NoSuchJobException, Exception {
    [method......]

    return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParameters);
}

}
```

XML config looked something like that:

```
<si:service-activator input-channel="bean1-input"
        output-channel="job-requests" ref="bean1JobLauncher" />

<bean id="bean1JobLauncher" class="com.example.ServiceActivatorClass">
    <property name="job" ref="bean1Job" />
    <property name="doneFolder" value="${done.dir.bean1}" />
    <property name="errorFolder" value="${error.dir.bean1}" />
    <property name="database" ref="database" />
```

---

```
<si:service-activator input-channel="bean2-input"
            output-channel="job-requests" ref="bean2JobLauncher" />

<bean id="bean2JobLauncher" class="com.example.ServiceActivatorClass">
    <property name="job" ref="bean2Job" />
    <property name="doneFolder" value="${done.dir.bean2}" />
    <property name="errorFolder" value="${error.dir.bean2}" />
    <property name="database" ref="database" />
```

X times...
Is removing the @MessageEnpoint and @ServiceActivator from the ServiceActivatorClass and doing something like that for Java Config....:

```
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="bean1Input", outputChannel="jobRequestsChannel")
    public MessageHandler bean1JobLauncher() {
        ServiceActivatorClass bean1JobLauncher = new ServiceActivatorClass();
        bean1JobLauncher.setJob(manifestJob());
        bean1JobLauncher.setDoneFolder(manifestDoneDir);
        bean1JobLauncher.setErrorFolder(manifestErrorDir);
        bean1JobLauncher.setDatabase(database);

        return new MethodInvokingMessageHandler(bean1JobLauncher, "adapt");
    }
```

...the good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's fine what you do so far. You can consider to move to Java DSL directly:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow bean1Flow() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from("bean1Input")
                     .handle(bean1JobLauncher(), null)
                     .channel("jobRequestsChannel")
                     .get();
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow bean2Flow() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from("bean2Input")
                     .handle(bean2JobLauncher(), null)
                     .channel("jobRequestsChannel")
                     .get();
}
```

Or you can consider a delegation variant:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="bean1Input", outputChannel="jobRequestsChannel")
public JobLaunchRequest adapt1(File file) {
    return bean1JobLauncher().adapt(file);
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="bean2Input", outputChannel="jobRequestsChannel")
public JobLaunchRequest adapt2(File file) {
    return bean2JobLauncher().adapt(file);
}
```

But there is no other way to distribute logic between different channels and different target components. You have to declare them separately, even if there is some amount of copy/paste.

You may consider to use dynamic flow registration though, but that's already a different story and doesn't look like a strong requirement in your case: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows

Comment: thank you. With the introduction of IntegrationFlow I would have to keep the MessageEndpoint and ServiceActivator annotations on the class right?

Comment: Well, not necessarily, but won't hurt to have them there. you have to declare your `ServiceActivatorClass` as a `@Bean` several times anyway - for different configuration options. The `@ServiceActivator` helps here only for method scanning, but if you use its name explicitly, it doesn't matter anymore.